# How to readInput regardless of type in scala?

Tags: scala

Hi im fairly new to scala and I want to do a type check on a number a user enters. Is there a way in scala to read from the user and let scala determine which type it thinks it is.

Comment: Well if you dont define a data type when declaring a variable  then it decides which ones fits best ... just meant in that sense when reading an input?

Comment: it doesn't "decide which one fits", it just looks at what you assign to the variable. If you read the input as a string, it will be string, if you read it as a byte array, it will be that.

Comment: @Dima how can I do a type check to make sure the user doesnt enter in data of the wrong type then

Comment: `if ( Try { stringInput.toInt }.toOption.isEmpty ) println("this is not an int")`

Comment: @Dima thank you just used a try catch was a really dumb question tbh sry

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do like the following:
Suppose a is the number entered

```
     a match {
      case a: Byte => println("It is byte")
      case a: Short => //do something
      case a: Int => //do something
      case a: Long => //do something
      case a: Float => //do something
      case a: Double => //do something
      case _ => println("It is not a number")
    }
```

Comment: I am already using code similar to this and it works but this isnt really the problem I was asking. I wanted to know if u can read what the user puts regardless off what it is. ie if they are meant to put an int and they put a string instead I use the code you put above to do make them input another number until they input a valid one. Its just things like readInt() would  terminate the program if the user put anything other than a Int